# The Filter geometry function in T-SQL is not precise and does not return valid results

Tags: sql, intersection, graph

I have two tables, edges (a set of polyline features):

[image]

and nodes (set of points):

[image]

I want to find the "**id**" of those points that have an intersection with the first point of any edges. I used the STIntersects() function in SQL and wrote down the below script :

```
select EdgeTable.id, NodeTable.idj, 
from EdgeTable inner join NodeTable
ON NodeTable.GeomJ.STIntersects(EdgeTable.StartPointG) =1
```

This code works correctly, but the problem is with their performance. As a matter of fact, EdgeTable and NodeTable have about 2 million records and the execution time of the above script is about 55 minutes which is not at all suitable for my work.

Thus, I found [Filter](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geometry/filter-geometry-data-type) geometry function which seems to be a good solution for improving the performance of this task. In this regard, firstly I created the spatial index on my tables and then use this function as below:

```
select EdgeTable.id, NodeTable.idj,
from EdgeTable inner join NodeTable
ON NodeTable.GeomJ.Filter(EdgeTable.StartPointG) =1
```

But this function returns completely wrong results. For example, I tested the script for the edge 1 (idj = 1) which the start point of this edge intersects with node 1 , this is the result of STIntersects() function :

[image]

and this for Filter function:

[image]

Due to description of Filter geometry function, it remarked that **this method is not deterministic and is not precise**. Hence, why the results of these two functions are different and how can I come up with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [doc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geometry/filter-geometry-data-type) says it is an **index-only intersection method**, meaning it tests for the geometries bounding box intersection. The doc further says that it returns false positive but not false negatives, so you can benefit from it by using this fast method to find **potential** intersections, then you refine the results in the `where clause` using the slow `st_intersects` (which runs on a dozen of points instead of a few millions)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It returns the correct answer, but no change in time performance. I tested your hint for a bit large table and calculated the execution time which was exactly the same with the single STIntersect() function.

Comment: @Mohammad This should be a different (new) question that should contain your indexes and the execution plan. Please consider accepting this answer (green check mark to the left) so other know it is a working solution for the original question